# How can I delay/lazy evaluate an argument to a function in Racket?

Tags: racket, lazy-evaluation, divide-by-zero

I'm am staying within #lang racket.
I am trying to figure out how to delay a function argument from being evaluated - I cannot change the argument being passed in.
For example, say I wanted to pass in do something like this:

`(define (a e) 6)`

Then I want to call a with this argument

`(a (/ 1 0))`

How can I delay the evaluation of this argument?

I tried doing something like (in the function a):

`(define (a e) 
  (define E (lambda () e)) 
     6)`

But this still evaluates the argument first. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

`#lang racket` is an eager language, but as it's earlier generation was a R5RS Scheme it still has R5RS compatible `delay` and `force`:

```scm
(define (test delayed-e) 6)
(test (delay (/ 1 0)))
; ==> 6
```

Without the special forms you could do:

```scm
(test (thunk (/ 1 0)))
; ==> 6

;; the same as
(test (lambda () (/ 1 0)))
; ==> 6
```

Notice in both you need to do it when you call the functions since you need to wrap the values before the language evaluates them. In a lazy language like `#lang lazy` you can write the code naively and it will do the correct thing.

```scm
#lang lazy

(define (test e) 6)
(test (/ 1 0))
; ==> 6
```

Now an implementation of `#lang lazy` would be to have  macro that decorates with `delay` and `force` so the core might be the same with just slightly different surface language.  If there was as easy to use lazy evaluation in an eager language we wouldn't have the use for lazy languages.

**EDIT**

Macros are a way to do computation on the actual code. Thus if you made your function a macro instead you could have it turn into whatever you'd like:

```scm
(define-syntax test 
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ ignored-edpression) 6)))

(test (/ 1 0))
; ==> 6
```

Not it's important to know that this replaces the code with `6`. You could instead make it wrap:

```scm
(define-syntax define-lazy
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (name args ...) body ...)
     (begin
       (define (impl args ...)
         body ...)
       (define-syntax name
         (syntax-rules ()
           ((_ margs (... ...)) (impl (delay margs) (... ...)))))))))

(define-lazy (test e) 6)
(test (/ 1 0))
; ==> 6
```

If you look at what this expands `(test (/1 0))` to it will look like the first example. Unlike the lazy languages you would need to `force` the arguments in the body explicitly though.

```scm
(define-lazy (my-if p c a)
  (if (force p)
      (force c)
      (force a)))

(my-if (< 3 4) 10 (/ 1 0))
; ==> 10
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without modifying the function arguments? As in the argument became (delay (/ 1 0)) instead of just (/ 1 0).

Comment: @Chubbles Perhaps you can make a macro that is called test that expands to delaying its arguments. You need to work around the eagerness of `#lang racket` evaluation model so it will require effort. Using `#lang lazy` will not.

Comment: @Chubbles I've added a macro example.

Comment: That my-if example you posted, that's kinda what I wanted to go for. Like if I was passed in let's say 3 arguments, the last one being some (/ 1 0); obviously the function will evaluate the args, but I don't want it to. I want to be able to use the functions on the first two args only and perhaps use the third argument.

Comment: @Chubbles You're welcome. It might be cleaner in an eager language to do it with explicit macros or use Lazy racket that is made for this though.

Comment: So if I wanted to use this define-syntax-rule as a function, could I do that?

Comment: @Chubbles You cannot, but if you can think of code that does the same as what ou are trying to achieve you can use a macro to rewrite from the macro form to the desired resulting code to be evaluated. eg. `cond` is just nested `if` with `begin`. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: `#lang racket` isn’t an R5RS Scheme.

Comment: @AlexisKing True, but it is derived from a previous  R5RS superset. I would say `#lang racket` is a scheme dialect in the sense I call JavaScript, and Perl C(B) dialects.